# What does >+ symbol represent in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps pipeline:

```yaml
task: CmdLine@2
Inputs:
  script: >+
    echo “Hello”
```

What does `>+` after script mean? Similarly I have noticed

- `script: >-`
- `script: >`
- `script: |`

What is the difference between all of these?

I think `script: |` means multi line command

Answer (score 1):

'|' and '>' are YAML symbols for **[scalars](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#23-scalars)**:

- '|' indicates that the value is a multiline string, and **the YAML interpreter must preserve the text 'as-is**,' including all line breaks.
- '>' indicates that it is a single-line value split into several lines. **The interpreter will replace the new lines with spaces.**

'+' and '-' are **[Block Chomping Indicators](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#8112-block-chomping-indicator)** that instruct the YAML interpreter on how to handle line breaks and empty lines at the end of the value:

- '+' means the interpreter must **retain** all empty lines and line breaks at the end of the value.
- '-' means the interpreter must **remove** empty lines and line breaks at the end of the value.